# Why does the Rails.cache.write return a different value in Rails 2.3.11 and Rails 3.2.11 console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-2

I am trying to expire key in 10 seconds, somehow it is, but not working with rspec. In this process, I noticed `Rails.cache.write` return `false` in Rails 2.3.11, while `Rails.cache.write` return `true` in Rails 3.2.11, is this a problem? why different value? Why Rails 2.3.11 return `false` and `Rails 3.2.11` return `true`?

```
Rails 2.3.11

irb(main):001:0> Rails.cache.write("test", "java", :expires_in => 10.seconds)
=> false

Rails 3.2.11

irb(main):001:0> Rails.cache.write("test", "java", :expires_in => 10.seconds)
=> true
```

I am using jruby 1.6.5.1 with Rails 2.3.11 and jruby 1.7.3 with Rails 3.2.11.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500142/rails-cache-read-returns-nil-in-rails-but-not-in-console

Comment: @CodeGroover - that's not solved my problem, I checked if I make it config.cache_classes true, doesn't change my output that I placed in question

Comment: i'm sure that problem in env diff.

Comment: @CodeGroover if I make it config.cache_classes true for Rails 2.3.11 and restart console, I am not seeing any difference, same apply for Rails 3.2.11

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `Rails.cache.write` method is what is sometimes known as a *command* method, which is called for its side effects, as opposed to a *query* method, called for its return value (for more info, check out [command-query separation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-query_separation)).

Since [the Rails docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Cache/Store.html#method-i-write) make no guarantees about the return value, it is probably best not to depend on it, since it might (and apparently has) change without warning.